# Hello, I am building a query to 1. Find jobs from consulting companies located in Chicago

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following tables in SQL:

- Company (compid, compname, comptype)
- Job (jobid, jobtitle, salarylow, salaryhigh, location, compid*)
- Skills (skillid, skillname)
- Jobskills (jobid, skillid, expertiseneeded)
- Applicant (appid, name, age, highdegree, expected_salary)
- AppSkills (appid, skillid, expertise)
- Applies (jobid, appid, appdate, decisiondate, outcome)

And when I run this code in Oracle developer:

```
select 
    j.jobid, j.jobtitle
from 
    Job as j
inner join 
    Company as c on j.compid = c.compid
where 
    c.comtype = 'consulting'
    and j.location = 'Chicago';
```

then I get this error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: What happens if you remove the ending `;`?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, table aliases don't allow the `AS` keyword:

```
select 
    j.jobid, j.jobtitle
from 
    Job as j                                 --> remove AS here ...
inner join 
    Company as c on j.compid = c.compid      --> ... and here
where 
    c.comtype = 'consulting'
    and j.location = 'Chicago';
```